# Amazon RDS unable to execute SET GLOBAL command

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am using Amazon RDS for mysql db. I want to run some SET commands for eg:

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len =18446744073709551615
```

But when I run this command I get this error

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

When I try to add privileges, it does not allow me to add. Any help or inputs?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Amazon does not give you SUPER privileges on an RDS instance (to prevent you from breaking things like replication accidentally).

To configure `group_concat_max_len`, use an RDS parameter group, which allows you to configure a group of settings to apply to an instance.

[image]

Comment: For more on RDS parameter groups, check out [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=183618) from the AWS Forums (you'll need to log in with AWS credentias). This thread provides a few more examples. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz so you mean I should create my own parameter group and edit what I want and use that instead?

Comment: @chandresh_cool Yes. The default settings are reasonable, but if you have a compelling reason for overriding them you'd need to create a new parameter group and apply it to your RDS instance.

Comment: @ceejayoz I did this parameter group configuration and even with that i still getting the same 1024 characters in GROUP_CONCAT, is there anything else to do after setting the parameter groups?

Comment: Any ideas how to have this work for serverless? this is a modifiable parameter only in the provisioned engine

Answer (score 2):

With RDS global settings are managed via the [ParameterGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html) API. You can also edit them from the web console or using the aws command line tools.