# AWS RDS Super Privileges

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-error-1045

We have AWS RDS instance. We would like to track database user login details like the last login. For this, we have written a stored procedure and we would like to call that procedure on the event `init_connect`. But we are not able to set the trigger. I am using below command to set it up.

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect="CALL track.log_trigger()"  
and I am getting below error.
```

> Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER
>   privilege(s) for this operation.

But when I try to set the super to user it again gives an error.

```
grant super on *.* to user1;
```

> Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password:
>   YES) so unable to use it by normal user, by root user and unable to
>   set SET GLOBAL init_connect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon RDS unable to execute SET GLOBAL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147206/amazon-rds-unable-to-execute-set-global-command)