# Django + Celery. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql, django, celery

I have a Django app that run some chained tasks with celery. 
The first task asks an external app for it's DB dump, the second one downloads it and the third is the one that is giving me problems.

- First of all it unzips the dump through Popen, it takes like 30 minutes.
- After that it runs a sed command also through Popen that deletes a few tables that I won't use. This sed command takes like one hour
- Finally I run a Popen once more to restore the dump

```
proc = Popen([
            "mysql", "-h{}".format(settings.MYSQL_HOST), "-u{}".format(settings.MYSQL_USER),
            "-p{}".format(settings.MYSQL_PASSWORD), snapshot_restore.database_name
        ], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, stdin=sed_dumpfile)
```

This process takes 8 hours approximately.

- Once the restore is finished it updates a django model in the DB, and that singal should triggers the next task.

```
snapshot_restore = SnapshotRestore.objects.get(id=snapshot_restore_id)
snapshot_restore.status = "processing"
snapshot_restore.save()

# Here I make the unzip, the sed and the restore

snapshot_restore.status = "finished"
snapshot_restore.database_status = "active"
snapshot_restore.save()
```

But here is when I have this error

```
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 266, in _set_autocommit
    self.connection.autocommit(autocommit)
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 256, in autocommit
    _mysql.connection.autocommit(self, on)
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] File "/srv/src/core/tasks.py", line 243, in restore_snapshot_task
    snapshot_restore.save()
```

## I already tried a few things to solve this.

### First of all tried to get the entity again before saving it:

```
    try:
        snapshot_restore.save()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Error updating snapshot_restore status, will retry.')
        snapshot_restore = SnapshotRestore.objects.get(id=snapshot_restore_id)
        snapshot_restore.status = "finished"
        snapshot_restore.database_status = "active"
        snapshot_restore.save()
```

But kept having the same error

```
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,701: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] core.tasks.restore_snapshot_task[None]: restore complete in 28783.03s
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,701: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] core.tasks.restore_snapshot_task[None]: Error updating snapshot_restore status, will retry.
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,720: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] --- Logging error ---
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,722: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 266, in _set_autocommit
    self.connection.autocommit(autocommit)
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 256, in autocommit
    _mysql.connection.autocommit(self, on)
[2020-04-19 11:33:20,723: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

### Incrementing MySql interactive_timeout

I tried to increment the MySql idle connection time (interactive_timeout), since it it an AWS RDS instance I had to do it through parameter groups, like I found here:

[Amazon RDS unable to execute SET GLOBAL command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147206/amazon-rds-unable-to-execute-set-global-command)

I set it to 12 hours before killing an idle connection, but still getting the same "Lost connection" error.

### Created a separate thread that keeps querying de DB

I wrote this function

```
def keep_connection_alive(id, stop):
    logger.info("Starting keep_connection_alive iteration id: " + str(id))
    while True:
        time.sleep(600)
        try:
            SnapshotRestore.objects.get(id=randrange(10))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Error keeping alive: ' + str(e))
        if stop():
            print('Stopping keep_connection_alive')
            break
    logger.info('keep_connection_alive out of while')
```

And called it at the beginning of the task like this

```
stop_thread = False
keep_alive_thread = threading.Thread(target=keep_connection_alive, args=(1, lambda: stop_thread))
keep_alive_thread.start()
```

I had a lot of

```
[2020-04-19 07:46:47,523: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] ???[???]: Error keeping alive: SnapshotRestore matching query does not exist.
```

Because most of the times, the id didn't exist. I ran this code two times, the first one I got the error like 8 hours after starting the process

```
[2020-04-18 10:28:35,893: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] ???[???]: Error keeping alive: SnapshotRestore matching query does not exist.
[2020-04-18 10:38:36,016: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] ???[???]: Error keeping alive: SnapshotRestore matching query does not exist.
[2020-04-18 10:52:56,766: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] ???[???]: Error keeping alive: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
[2020-04-18 11:02:56,867: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] ???[???]: Error keeping alive: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
[2020-04-18 11:12:56,955: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-2] ???[???]: Error keeping alive: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

And the second time I got it when it was trying to save the restore

```
snapshot_restore.save()
```

### Where to go from here?

I have only one idea left, and it's to trigger another celery tasks that just changes the state of the model, so the signal will also be triggered and the next task will start.
But beside testing that and praying for it to work, I would like to understand why is this happening and if there's a possible solution.

Thanks in advance!